# Como criar macro que retorna data do arquivo em uma célula EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Preciso de uma macro que pegue a data do arquivo, onde eu vou deixar o caminho especificado. E essa data do arquivo será inserida na célula B3 por exemplo, é possivel?

Macro que consegui até o momento, pesquisando na net, acredito que para este caso seria com o FileDate

```html
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'

Worksheets("CCD").Activate

Range("B3").Select


Dim LResult As Date

LResult = FileDateTime("Z:\Álax\TAREFA JEFF\ARQUIVO FINAL\BLOCO DE NOTAS\BLOCO DE NOTAS2\ACS_SUPVA_20220622.txt")


FileDateTime ("Z:\Álax\TAREFA JEFF\ARQUIVO FINAL\BLOCO DE NOTAS\BLOCO DE NOTAS2\ACS_SUPVA_20220622.txt")
Result: '6/1/2004 7:40:18 PM'

Range("C1").Insert


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Experimente a seguinte função:

```
Function UltimaData(caminho As String)

UltimaData = FileDateTime(caminho)

End Function
```

Depois é só chamar a função "UltimaData" na célula pretendida e indicar o caminho como no exemplo:

```
=UltimaData("Z:\Álax\TAREFA JEFF\ARQUIVO FINAL\BLOCO DE NOTAS\BLOCO DE NOTAS2\ACS_SUPVA_20220622.txt")
```

Coloque assim como está na [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kr9r.jpg) (Fora da SUB)

Comment: Está dando problema com o End Sub por causa desse End Function,

Comment: Olha como estou fazendo: https://imgur.com/b5ajOhj

Comment: Acrescentei imagem de exemplo de como deve ficar no VBE.

Comment: Opa, tudo certo! Entendi, porém percebi agora que não preciso exatamente da data do arquivo. Sabe como poderia pegar o que está escrito no nome do arquivo e inserir na célula? por exemplo: Esse é o arquivo, quero que ao importar ele pegue somente a data nele e retorne na célula escolhida: https://imgur.com/zyYUD4x

Comment: Pois o usuário pode enviar o txt outro dia, sem ser a data exata que foi gerada então acredito que para evitar isso seja melhor pegar pelo nome. E não pela data exata do arquivo, mas isso vai me ajudar com outro trabalho inclusive! Então agradeço mesmo assim

Answer (score -2):

Para realizar a leitura da data grafada no nome do arquivo, no padrão que foi disponibilizado, utilize esta rotina:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnExtrairDataConstanteDoNomeDoArquivo()
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strFileName As String

    strFileName = "Z:\Álax\TAREFA JEFF\ARQUIVO FINAL\BLOCO DE NOTAS\BLOCO DE NOTAS2\ACS_SUPVA_20220622.txt"
    strDate = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, ".") - 1)
    strDate = Right(strDate, 8)
    strDate = VBA.DateValue(Right(strDate, 2) & "/" & Mid(strDate, 5, 2) & "/" & Left(strDate, 4))
    MsgBox strDate

End Sub
```

Adapte à sua realidade.

Editado:

Para executar esta rotina recebendo parâmetros, transforme-a em uma Function:

```
Option Explicit

Function fnExtrairDataConstanteDoNomeDoArquivo(ByVal strFileName As String) As String
    Dim strDate As String

    strDate = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, ".") - 1)
    strDate = Right(strDate, 8)
    strDate = VBA.DateValue(Right(strDate, 2) & "/" & Mid(strDate, 5, 2) & "/" & Left(strDate, 4))
    fnExtrairDataConstanteDoNomeDoArquivo = strDate

End Function

Sub TestarAFunction()
    MsgBox fnExtrairDataConstanteDoNomeDoArquivo("C:\Temp\Teste_20220711.TXT")
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok Alex, isso resolveria meu problema! Consegui adaptar de modo que insira a data na célula que escolhi, porém só tem um problema pertinente nisso.

Comment: Nessa macro tem caminho definido para o documento "ACS_SUPVA_20220622.txt" porém nem sempre será esse mesmo txt, como poderia contornar isso? Pensei em algum modo que no lugar desse caminho, ele pegue o nome do arquivo que foi importado e faça isso